# C++ different constructor calls

Tags: c++, constructor

I wrote a little class to learn the different constructor calls

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

class String {
    private:
        char *str;

    public:
        explicit String(const char *p);
        String(String&& StringObject);
        String(String& stringObject);
        ~String();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& s);
        friend String operator+(const String& s1, const String& s2);
};

String::String(const char *p)
{
    size_t l = strlen(p) + 1;
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * l);
    if (str)
        strcpy(str, p);
    std::cout << "constructor call" << std::endl;
}
String::String(String& stringObject)
{
    str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(stringObject.str) + 1));
    strcpy(str, stringObject.str);
    std::cout << "copy constructor call" << std::endl;
}

String::~String()
{
    free(str);
}

String::String(String&& stringObject)
{
    this->str = stringObject.str;
    stringObject.str = nullptr;
    std::cout << "move constructor call" << std::endl;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const String& s)
{
    return os << s.str;
}

String operator+(const String& s1, const String& s2)
{
    size_t sl1 = strlen(s1.str);
    size_t sl2 = strlen(s2.str);
    char str[sl1 + sl2 + 1];
    strcpy(str, s1.str);
    strcpy(str+sl1, s2.str);

    return String{str};
}

String doNothing(String obj)
{
    std::cout << "output in function: " << obj << std::endl;

    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    String s1("text");
    String s2("and more text");

    std::cout << "output: " << s1 << std::endl;
    String s3 = doNothing(s1+ String{" "} + s2);
    String s4 = doNothing(s1);

    String s5 = s1 + s4;
}
```

The output is

```
constructor call
constructor call
output: text
constructor call
constructor call
constructor call
output in function: text and more text
move constructor call
copy constructor call
output in function: text
move constructor call
constructor call
```

I think the constructor calls on line 4 to 6 come from the method call

```
String s3 = doNothing(s1+ String{" "} + s2);
```

Why does the method call not cause a call to the copy constructor like the second method call?

```
String s4 = doNothing(s1);
```

Maybe because s1 is a lvalue?

Can the move constructor only be called when a function returns an object or also when a reference or pointer to an object is returned?

Comment: The expression `s1+ String{" "} + s2`  will construct `String` instances BEFORE calling `doNothing()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suppose that you start line counting at 1 ;-)

### The case with a complex expression

We would expect the following statement to construct in principe a temporary `String` for `String{" "}`, and then a temporary string for each of the two `+`.  Since the parameter `obj` is to be constructed from a temporary object, the move constructor could be used:

```
String s3 = doNothing(s1+ String{" "} + s2);
```

The idea, of the move constructor is to be able to take advantage of the fact that the original object is disposable.

The return value of the function is also a temporary value and this one is used to construct `s3` with the move constructor.

But shouldn't we then have 3 constructors and two move constructors?  No,  because there are **[copy elision rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)**.  These cause the compiler to avoid unnecessary a copies/moves, and construct directly into the target.  This happens here for the parameter.

### The case with the lvalue

The next statement constructs the parameter `obj` with the copy constructor of an lvalue `s1`:

```
String s4 = doNothing(s1);
```

This is less surprising. The value is in principle copied to a temporary return value,  which is then used to move-construct s4 from a temporary.

But again,  copy elision simplifies this to a copy constructor and a move.

### Analysing what happens

You could analyse more in detail what happens, by displaying the address of the object.  This is very helpful to understand what happens on what object:

```
class String {...};

String::String(const char *p)
{
    size_t l = strlen(p) + 1;
    str = new char[l];
    if (str)
        strcpy(str, p);
    std::cout << "constructor call:" << this<<"="<<str<< std::endl;
}
String::String(const String& stringObject)
{
    str = new char[ strlen(stringObject.str) + 1];
    strcpy(str, stringObject.str);
    std::cout << "copy constructor call:" <<this<<"="<<str<< std::endl;
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] str;
}

String::String(String&& stringObject)
{
    this->str = stringObject.str;
    stringObject.str = nullptr;
    std::cout << "move constructor call:"<<this <<"="<<str<< std::endl;
}

String operator+(const String& s1, const String& s2)
{
    size_t sl1 = strlen(s1.str);
    size_t sl2 = strlen(s2.str);
    char str[sl1 + sl2 + 1];
    strcpy(str, s1.str);
    strcpy(str+sl1, s2.str);

    return String{str};
}

String doNothing(String obj)
{
    std::cout << "output in function: " <<&obj<<":"<< obj << std::endl;
    return obj;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/apa8mU)

### Unrelated advice

I highly recommend that you get rid of `malloc()` and `free()` in C++  so I used here `new[]` and `delete[]` (or `new` and `delete` if it's not about arrays).  In a second step you could alsoe get rid of the `strcpy()`

Comment: I normally use char arrays instead of malloc but in this case not. Why? I don't know. I'll memorize that! What can I use instead of `strcpy`? Did you mean `std::string` or `strncpy`?

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer I meant [std::copy()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) which is a general algorithm for all kind of containers. And since it is length or upper-bound based, there are less risk than with strcpy()